# Using a while loop only once

Tags: python, smtplib

I am working on a simple program to email me the weather in my city each morning. At the moment, it works, but only once. Using a while loop works, but since I have it set to,

```
while time == 0600:
    send my mail etc
```

Now obviously, that makes it so for the entirety of that minute, I get spammed with mail. So I need to figure out a way for something to happen once, every 24 hours.

Here is my full code (currently only working once, until I restart it).

```
import smtplib, pywapi, datetime
weather = True
loopmsg = True
loopmsg1 = True
def send():
    loopmsg = True
    loopmsg1 = True
    global weather
    while weather == True:
        if loopmsg == True:
            print('Initial Loop Initiated')
            loopmsg = False
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time = str(time)
        time = time[11:]
        time = time[:-10]
        time = time.replace(":", "")
        time = int(time)
        fromaddr = 'xxx'
        toaddrs  = 'xxx'
        while time == 0600:
            print('Time is correct')
            weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('ASXX0075')
            msg = "It is " + weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'].lower() + " and " + weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'] + "°C in Your City."
            msg = msg.encode('utf-8')

            # Credentials (if needed)
            username = 'xxx'
            password = 'xxx'

            # The actual mail send
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
            server.starttls()
            server.login(username,password)
            server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
            server.quit()
            print('Sent')
            #weather = False

    #while weather == False:
      #  if loopmsg1 == True:
         #   print('Second Loop Initiated')
         #   loopmsg1 = False
       # while time > 0600:
           # send()

send()
```

Comment: Why `while`, when an `if` will only run it once? Anyway: 1. add a flag `sentMail` and set it to `True` inside the send routine. 2. Don't send when `sentMail` is `True`. 3. Add a new `if time == 0601` that resets `sentMail` to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're running a script all day long for it to do something only once a day. This is illogical. You should schedule a task on your OS (Win, Linux, Mac - they all have a way to schedule tasks) so that your script is activated at 6h every day; and remove the time condition inside your script.

If you want to get fancy, create a Telegram bot and have it send you a message any time you want, on your phone, for the location you specify right then.

The script however is easy to fix. You're using that `while` loop as an `if`. Just add a variable that will make it send an e-mail only once.

```
if time == 0500:
    send_email = True
if send_email and time == 0600:
    print('Time is correct')
    send_email = False
    weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('ASXX0075')
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a break statement right after you send the email? This just causes you to break out of the loop. Then it will execute the rest of the program.

```
while time == 0600:
        print('Time is correct')
        weather_com_result = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('ASXX0075')
        msg = "It is " + weather_com_result['current_conditions']['text'].lower() + " and " + weather_com_result['current_conditions']['temperature'] + "°C in Your City."
        msg = msg.encode('utf-8')

        # Credentials (if needed)
        username = 'xxx'
        password = 'xxx'

        # The actual mail send
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
        server.quit()
        print('Sent')
        break
```